# Using new experimental Node's EventTarget class with ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to try the new DOM-compatible [`EventTarget`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_eventtarget_and_event_api) class which is [available as of Node.js 14.7.0](https://www.nearform.com/blog/node-js-and-the-struggles-of-being-an-eventtarget/).

I'm only able to do so if I use it from a `CommonJS` module, but not from an ES6 module. For example:

Running `node --expose-internals test.js` works, where `test.js` is:

```
const { Event, EventTarget } = require('internal/event_target');

const et = new EventTarget();
```

If I use it from an ES6 module, I'm getting an error:

`test.mjs`:

```
import { Event, EventTarget } from 'internal/event_target';

const et = new EventTarget();
```

Running `node --expose-internals test.mjs` fails with:

`SyntaxError: The requested module 'internal/event_target' does not provide an export named 'Event'`

Is there a way to make it work with ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it only exposes a default export which is an object, not named exports. So you have to import the default and then use destructuring:

```
import event_target from 'internal/event_target';
const { Event, EventTarget } = event_target;

const et = new EventTarget();
```

Comment: That works, many thanks! By chance, is there any command line option or an environment variable to make it work by default, without having to import `internal/event_target`?

Comment: @noseratio - You mean, so you can just do `const { Event, EventTarget } = event_target;`? Or just use `Event` and `EventTarget` without having to do anything? I don't know of an environment variable or `package.json` setting (but then I'm not a Node.js expert), but your entry module could always make them globals: `import event_target from "internal/event_target"; ({Event: globalThis.Event, EventTarget: globalThis.EventTarget} = event_target);` Then all other modules in the app would have access to them as globals.

Comment: I thought, maybe there's a way to make  `EventTarget` just be available in the global namespace without `import` at all, same as it is readily available in the browser. But maybe that's impossible. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @noseratio - There may be a better way I'm not aware of, but otherwise the code in the comment above does that if it's in the entry point module.

Comment: I've ended up using it for testing only, it's a module that can be used in both Node (where I still use EventEmitter) and Browser (where I used EventTarget). You answer works great for this purpose.